# How to use underscore/javascript templates in ASP.Net MVC views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I was just wondering how you use the underscore templates in a .aspx view since the <%=  %> tags that underscore uses get picked up by the .aspx rendering engine and give me errors.

For instance:

```
<script type="text/template" id="my-template">
  <span class="event" title="<%= description %>">
      <%= title %>
  </span>
</script>
```

This template gives me an error since the .aspx rendering engine thinks I'm trying to bind this stuff to the Model.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://underscorejs.org/#template):

> **template** `_.template(templateString, [data], [settings])`
>   [...]
>   If ERB-style delimiters aren't your cup of tea, you can change Underscore's template settings to use different symbols to set off interpolated code. Define an **interpolate** regex to match expressions that should be interpolated verbatim, an **escape** regex to match expressions that should be inserted after being HTML escaped, and an **evaluate** regex to match expressions that should be evaluated without insertion into the resulting string.

So if the default `<%=...%>`, `<%-...%>`, and `<%...%>` delimiters aren't working for you then you can use different ones with a simple configuration change. For example, if you wanted to use `{%...%}` instead of `<%...%>`, then do this after `underscore.js` is loaded and before you use `_.template`:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
    escape:      /\{%-(.+?)%\}/g,
    evaluate:    /\{%(.+?)%\}/g
};
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/TfB5M/