# Using underscore templating with ASP.NET controls

Tags: asp.net, .net, underscore.js

I am trying to use underscores templating system in my project. Now the issue is that we have a lot of server side (ASP.NET) controls as well that I would like to use. Is there any way to use the ASP.NET controls together with underscore templates?

I tried simulating a template as an aspx page to get the rendered html from there and then use the result but that seems like an overkill.

I am pretty new to templating so I have no idea about what to expect.

**EDIT:**

What I meant was, is there any way I can have e.g. an ASP.NET button inside an underscore template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just thought that it might help someone. One of the controls I wanted to use was a devexpress grid in my view. Now I could have done a "view source" on the grid and copied the rendered html to generate the view. However, I decided to create an aspx page and did an ajax call to the aspx page and displayed the resultant html in the view. I was hoping there would be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't with ASP.NET Controls (which use the `runat="server"` attribute), but with ASP.NET's Render function syntax `<% %>`.

See this earlier QA: [How to use underscore/javascript templates in ASP.Net MVC views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016316/how-to-use-underscore-javascript-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-views) the solution is to configure underscore.js to use a different delimiter:

This:

```
_.templateSettings = {
    interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
    escape:      /\{%-(.+?)%\}/g,
    evaluate:    /\{%(.+?)%\}/g
};
```

...will let you use `{% %}` as delimiters instead of `<% %>`.

Comment: I think I may have to paraphrase the question. What I meant was, is there any way I can have e.g. an ASP.NET button inside an underscore template? I know it sounds like a stupid question but I just had to ask :)