# underscore template conflicts in asp.net page

Tags: underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

Here is a underscore template whose chances to work within a Asp.net page are weak. Since `<%` is understood as opening tag for `asp.net` ( `MVC` and `WebForm`) code, can someone tell me how do I insert the following code in a asp.net page?

```
 <script type="text/html" id='div-data'>
  <% _.each(items,function(item,key,list){ %>
    <div><%= key %></div>
    <div><%= item.name %></div>
  <% }) %>
 </script>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use underscore/javascript templates in ASP.Net MVC views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016316/how-to-use-underscore-javascript-templates-in-asp-net-mvc-views)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost solved! I'd like to post this answer because It may help others...

I had to configure `underscore` to tell him that he must escape the asp.net render function `<% %>`

```
  _.templateSettings = {
interpolate: /\{%=(.+?)%\}/g,
escape:      /\{%-(.+?)%\}/g,
evaluate:    /\{%(.+?)%\}/g
 };
```

Now I can use `{% %}` instead. 
Thank you